# Signing XML (XML-DSig) using HSM and PKCS11 token in .Net Core 7.0

Tags: c#, pkcs#11, xml-dsig, signedxml

I have X509 certificate which contains public key only in my database. The corresponding private key is store inside HSM. I found out that SignedXml class in .NET does not support signing XML in HSM.

Is there any other alternative? A replacement for SignedXml or other option that I can use to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pkcs11Interop.X509Store](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop.X509Store) library which provides easy to use PKCS#11 based X.509 certificate store and contains [`Pkcs11RsaProvider`](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop.X509Store/blob/0.1.0/src/Pkcs11Interop.X509Store/Pkcs11RsaProvider.cs) class inherited from [`System.Security.Cryptography.RSA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03h9zcez(v=vs.110).aspx) class that you can use as a [`SigningKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml.signingkey(v=vs.110).aspx) with [`SignedXml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

There's also a [code sample](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop.X509Store/blob/0.4.0/src/Pkcs11Interop.X509Store.Tests/SignedXmlTest.cs) available which demonstrates your use case.

Comment: I will take a look and try it out. Thanks for the recommendation.